# Getting RSSI from Wifi in iOS

Tags: ios, wifi

I am trying to get the Wifi Information like SSID, Signal strength and other wifi information. Is it possible to do so in iOS 9? I see this question has been asked before but they are outdated and even some answered, most of them are not working or depreciated. How can we be able to achieve so using iOS 8 or better.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note: You need `com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper` entitlement granted by Apple for this. I'll leave this here for posterity, but it does not solve the OP.

> You can get signal strength, but I'm not sure if it's the RSSI, from the `Network Extension Framework`
>  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkExtension/Reference/NEHotspotHelperClassRef/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NEHotspotHelper/supportedNetworkInterfaces
>  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkExtension/Reference/NEHotspotNetworkClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NEHotspotNetwork/signalStrength

Comment: Thanks @chedabob for these awesome links. I will have a go and see if I could achieve something out of this.